# How to expect result in test of controller in Nest.js?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs

**test.controller.ts**

```js
import { Controller, Get, Res } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('test')
export class TestController {
  @Get()
  check(@Res() response) {
    response.status(200).send();
  }
}
```

**test.controller.spec.ts**

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { TestController } from './test.controller';

describe('TestController', () => {
  let controller: TestController;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [TestController],
    }).compile();

    controller = module.get<TestController>(TestController);
  });
  
  describe('check', () => {
    it('should return status 200', async () => {
      const result = 'test'

      expect(await controller.check()).toBe(result);
    });
  )
});
```

Current code is like this.
I want status of 200 but I don't know how to expect result in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is easier to return response code "nestJS way":

```
@Get()
@HttpCode(200)
check(@Res() response) {
    // My Result
}
```

In the testing You can chain expect :

```
expect(200).expect(...MoreChecks)
```

Or in Fastify:

```
expect(result.statusCode).toEqual(200)
```

But there are alot more expressJS different than Fastify
Please Refer To : https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing

Comment: Thank you! If I add `@HttpCode(200)`, I don't need `response.status(200).send();` ?

Comment: @Take Yes, You don't need it

Comment: I got it, thank you. So, what else should I write?

Comment: @Take Sorry, what do you want more ? or what do you expect to do ?

Comment: Sorry. I just want to rerurn status 200. So what should I write instead of `response.status(200).send();`?

Comment: if you write @HttpCode(200) on any controller function it will return 200 status code